# JavaFX and TableView from SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I think this problem is like when you forget a semicolon in the code. I'm creating a list to show in a tableview but there is only one item

> nombrepaciente

that I'm not getting and I don't know why mi table is not showing just that item.

**Here is my bean**

```
public class CitaBeanTable {

    public SimpleStringProperty nombrepaciente = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty hora =      new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty estado =    new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty notas = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getHora() {
        return hora.get();
    }
    public String getEstado() {
        return estado.get();
    }
    public String getNotas() {
        return notas.get();
    }
    public String getNombrePaciente() {
        return nombrepaciente.get();
    }

}
```

**Here is my controller**

```
public class CitasController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TableView<CitaBeanTable> tblCitas;
    @FXML private TableColumn clnNombrePaciente;
    @FXML private TableColumn clnHora;
    @FXML private TableColumn clnEstado;
    @FXML private TableColumn clnNotas;
    ObservableList<CitaBeanTable> citasObservable;


    private final ListChangeListener<CitaBeanTable> selectorTableCita =
       new ListChangeListener<CitaBeanTable>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends CitaBeanTable> change) {
        ponerCitaSeleccionada();
        }
    };

    private void ponerCitaSeleccionada() {
    //Do Something.
    }

    public CitaBeanTable getTablaCitaSeleccionada() {

        if (tblCitas != null) {

            List<CitaBeanTable> tabla = 
                tblCitas.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

            if(tabla.size() == 1) {
            final CitaBeanTable competicionSeleccionada = tabla.get(0);
            return competicionSeleccionada;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void inicializarTablaCitas(){

    clnNombrePaciente.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CitaBeanTable, String>("nombrepaciente"));
    clnHora.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CitaBeanTable, String>("hora"));
    clnEstado.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CitaBeanTable, String>("estado"));
    clnNotas.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CitaBeanTable, String>("notas"));

    citasObservable = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    tblCitas.setItems(citasObservable);

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        this.inicializarTablaCitas();

        final ObservableList<CitaBeanTable> tablaCitaSel = 
            tblCitas.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        tablaCitaSel.addListener(selectorTableCita);

        List<CitaBean> arregloCitas = new ArrayList();
        XMLParserCita xmlParser = new XMLParserCita();
        XMLParserPaciente xmlParserPaciente = new XMLParserPaciente();

        try {

        arregloCitas = xmlParser.getCitasPorFecha(datePicker.getValue().toString());

        for (int i=0; i<arregloCitas.size(); i++) {

            CitaBeanTable citaTable = new CitaBeanTable();

            // This method is working fine.
            citaTable.nombrepaciente.
                set(xmlParserPaciente.
                getNombrePacientePorCodigo(arregloCitas.get(i).
                getCodigopaciente().toString()));

            citaTable.hora.set(arregloCitas.get(i).getHora());
            citaTable.estado.set(arregloCitas.get(i).getEstado());
            citaTable.notas.set(arregloCitas.get(i).getNotas());

            citasObservable.add(citaTable);
        }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my FXML:**

```
<TableView fx:id="tblCitas">
    <columns>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="251.0" text="Paciente" fx:id="clnNombrePaciente" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Hora" fx:id="clnHora" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="184.0" text="Estado" fx:id="clnEstado" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="180.0" text="Notas" fx:id="clnNotas" />
    </columns>
 </TableView>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you pass into the PropertyValueFactory is incorrect: it needs to match the get...() method.

I.e. you need

```
clnNombrePaciente.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CitaBeanTable, String>("nombrePaciente"));
```

(with an uppercase "P").

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that line when I was typing my question.

Comment: It's really strange beacuse I can see the "hour" variable value on my list. Actually I have like 4 more and every single variable is showing on the tableview working very fine! But my "name" variable value is not there :-(

Comment: Most likely cause is that your property in the PropertyValueFactory doesn't correctly match the getXXX method. But since you're typing the question independently of your actual code, it's pretty much impossible to help.

Comment: You are right I'm gonna edit my question with copy an paste. Thanks.